# Picking images from camera and album in iOS Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm working in the application where users will select multiple images from album or taking pictures from camera and send it to server via REST API. Size limit is 5MB for all images. Is there any way to determine the size of images while selecting it from UIImagePicker before loading into application?. Also suggest me the better approach do the same

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do it using built in UIImagePickerController. You can write your own asset picker.